# Put mortar on cement board for outdoor kitchen

Tags: kitchens, framing, outdoor, countertops

I am building an outdoor countertop and still thinking about what to "cover" for the bottom part:

[image]

[image]

To make it simple, I was thinking about some plain design like concrete looking.

[image]

Source: http://www.urbankitchendesign.com/fascinating-small-sinks-for-outdoor-kitchen-with-brown-granite-kitchen-countertop-and-black-glossy-one-door-kitchen-refrigerator/

Is it OK to put mortar outside of cement board? I am thinking it could be "uneven" but not sure if it's possible to perfect it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be like doing Sheetrock. Make sure to have the edges along the sides of the cement board meet. (Not the ends). Then use Fiberglas mesh tape and skim coat. If you use the edges there is a slight indent so the joint won't be noticeable. Butting the ends will cause a bulge that will require a much thicker coat to hide the joint. If you don't use the mesh tape it will crack and every seam will show in a few months. [tape like this](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/7383269606442268151?lsf=seller:8740,store:17030424266850706624&prds=oid:11652057481141487466&q=fiberglass+joint+tape&hl=en-us&ei=dqXBV_7FOde4jAPD_ovQDA&lsft=lsf:seller:8740,store:17030424266850706624,prds:oid:11652057481141487466,q:Extra+Strength+250+ft.+Self-Adhesive+Mesh+Drywall+Joint+Tape+FDW8550-U,lsfq:AA316er-PhlCK9U4WuSMrYN3ZdCgWR5W7zRt7x0yIRi37VEl4xEg8_7qKjtL50AYcO1ILKEsNilewlclwGmdM0IkHIRERaZfyg,hl:en-us,ei:dqXBV_7FOde4jAPD_ovQDA,cm_mmc:SEM%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-Pro-LIA-D22-MaterialsSupply%7C,gclid:COWkqIrp4c4CFYFofgoduuILMQ,gclsrc:aw.ds&lsft=gclid:COWkqIrp4c4CFYFofgoduuILMQ).

Comment: Which materials do I use so that I can sand down like sheetrock? Also can you elaborate a bit what you mean on "edges along the sides of the cement board meet"?

Comment: You can sand mortar but it is much tougher than Sheetrock sanding. whatever you decide it needs to be water resistant.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could plaster over cement board to achieve a look similar to your pictures, but making any plaster or stucco job look good ("perfect" and not "uneven", as you say) is an **art**.

Trade craftsmen spend years apprenticing before they are trusted with application of the finish coat. You may want to consider hiring an experienced plasterer if you want it to look "perfect".